How do I stop Xcode automatically creating certificates, IDs and profiles in Developer Portal
In Developer Portal > Certificates, IDs & Profiles, the list is full of test apps and projects. How do I stop Xcode from automatically creating these on a per project basis?

In your Project, go to the Target (esp. you App) and set the team to "None".
Or turn off "Automatically Manage Signing".
But keep in mind, Xcode does a lot of signing and provisioning in the course of a normal project life cycle. Let me put it this way, I haven't seen Apple try to write a document about how to manually handle all the tasks Xcode is doing.

Thanks. This is what I figured although I also worked out I can edit the project.pbxproj file within the AppName.xcodeproj package and change the CODE_SIGN_STYLE to Manual and DEVELOPMENT_TEAM to "" (i.e. empty string)

Yeah. That is consistent with what I've noted. (Anyone want to start an Xcode config file doc-project? :) )
